# What is the first element in a vector?

Tags: c++

I have a vector and I am adding elements using push_back.

When I am debugging I have added one element to the vector, but the vector contains elements for [0] and [1]. The [1] is the element which I pushed on, but [0] looks like some sort of nullable object.

The vector size is 2 also- even though I have only inserted once.

Later in my code I will traverse the vector using `vector_name[i]`. Initially I would start with `i=0`, does this mean with a vector you should use 1 (or some sort of iterator)?

Comment: Post a short example to illustrate. Element zero in a vector is like any other. My guess is that you say `vector<int> v (1);` This creates a vector of size 1, not with the first element being 1. Then when you `push_back`, you add onto the end.

Comment: Please add code on how you initialize the vector

Comment: Don't keep pointers to the elements.  Using push_back() will invalidate them when vector<> re-allocates its internal storage.

Comment: And your last question: yes, you can use an iterator, with no adverse side effects whatsoever. But in this case, it won't solve the problem!

Comment: @All. I was using resize to assign 1 element and then pushback was putting the element into position 1, rather than position 0. Fixed it now

Comment: @user997112, you don't have to worry about resizing/reserving unless you're putting in a lot of elements, but the function you're looking for is `reserve`. `push_back` will add through that space, not onto it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element should be `vector[0]`.

For example:

```
int anumber = 300;
std::vector<int> intvector;
intvector.push_back(anumber);

std::cout << intvector[0];
```

Will print `300`.